# 2 Select statements in 1 insert

Tags: sql, select, insert, inner-join

```
Insert into sold(invId, cusId, LCnumfk, Name, Category, Brand, Price, ExDate, Tags, Quantity, Barcode)   
Select I.Id, L.Id, L.LCnum, I.Name, I.Category, I.Brand, I.Price, I.ExDate, I.Tags, I.Quantity, I.Barcode from inventory as I   
INNER JOIN sold as S on I.Id = S.invId INNER JOIN loyaltycard as L on S.CusId = L.Id where I.Barcode = 356554745
```

First i have a table named inventory, sold and loyalty card. The table inventory consist of the column Name, Category, Brand , Price ... and the Loyalty Card has the column name of id and LCnum.. i want all of these values to insert into sold table.. how can i do this?

I tried this code and try my luck but still a no..

```
Insert into sold(invID, Name, Category, Brand, Price, ExDate, Tags, Quantity, Barcode)  
Select Id, Name, Category, Brand, Price, ExDate, Tags, Quantity, Barcode from inventory  
where Barcode = '3565547456644' 
Insert into sold(CusId, LCnumfk)   
Select Id, LCnum from loyaltycard where LCnum = '347'
```

Here is the structure of the database:

```
inventory(Id int , Name varchar(255), Category varchar(255), Brand varchar(255), Price int, ExDate date, Tags varchar(255), Quantity int, Barcode varchar(255))

sold(invId int, CusId int, LCnumfk int,Name varchar(255), Category varchar(255), Brand varchar(255), Price int, ExDate date, Tags varchar(255), Quantity int, Barcode varchar(255) ) 

loyaltycard(Id int, LCnum int)

sold foreign key LCnumfk has a constraint to loyaltycard LCnum

sold invId is a foreign key and has a constraint to inventory Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you perform 2 inserts - the first set will have CustId & LCnumfk as NULL. The second insert statement will have all other fields populated as NULL apart from CustId & LCnumfk.

This would result into invalid data.

**What needs to be done -**

> **Step 1 - Insert data**

```
Insert into sold(invID, Name, Category, Brand, Price, ExDate, Tags, Quantity, Barcode)  
Select Id, Name, Category, Brand, Price, ExDate, Tags, Quantity, Barcode from inventory  
where Barcode = '3565547456644'
```

> **Step 2 - Update the rows of 'sold' table inserted in step 1**

```
Update sold
SET CusId = (Select Id from loyaltycard where LCnum = '347'),
LCnumfk = (Select LCnum from loyaltycard where LCnum = '347')
```

Though you should replace the sub-query with a join in order to update all rows correctly.

Comment: In the Insert query there is an error. Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CusId', table 'sys.dbo.sold'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

i have this error when i try your query and i check the tables and it updated sold table only the CusId and LCnumfk. it does not insert the values

Comment: The insert query in the answer is the same query in the question. The reason you are getting this error is because it is violating the constraint on your `Sold` table

Comment: Could you share the structure of `Sold` table and `inventory` table. Is there some relation between the 2 tables?

Comment: yes. sold invId is a foreign key and has a constraint to inventory Id

Comment: Please share the table structure of - `inventory`, `sold`, `loyaltycard`

Comment: inventory(Id int , Name varchar(255), Category varchar(255), Brand varchar(255), Price int, ExDate date, Tags varchar(255), Quantity int, Barcode varchar(255)) --------- sold(invId int, CusId int, LCnumfk int,Name varchar(255), Category varchar(255), Brand varchar(255), Price int, ExDate date, Tags varchar(255), Quantity int, Barcode varchar(255) ) --------- loyaltycard(Id int, LCnum int) --------- sold foreign key LCnumfk has a constraint to loyaltycard LCnum,